# Get the most recent month and use the same day of given date

Tags: google-sheets

Need to find the most recent month of a given date and use the same day as the given month. The most recent date must be before today's date.

Here is my [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k1wKYSM634QmSAwZ-S7DfBEKMKPgcwwbo_iAmFPAQIA/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is a screenshot below:

[image]

Need the formula to be in the form of an array formula.

Comment: Your sheet is private. Please make it public.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try:

```
=map(B4:B,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,let(Λ,index(edate(Σ,sequence(datedif(Σ,A2,"m")+1))),xlookup(A2-1,Λ,Λ,,-1)))))
```